# How can I validate a decimal interval using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to code a store procedure in order to check if a new interval is currently stored in table.

Example:

I have these values on my table:

startHour = 7.20

endHour = 8.10

I want to find a way to cancel any insert with startHour or endHour that causes conflicts with te previous stored values, like startHour = 7.21, 7.32, 8.09 and so.
I mean, the interval 7.20 - 8.10 is not available.
And yeah, i'm using decimals.
Thanks!

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. From what you posted nobody can help much. You need to provide some details about your table, the data and what you are trying to do. sqlfiddle.com is a good place to start. And why are you using decimals? Why not use the time datatype?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like:

```
declare @startHour decimal
declare @endHour decimal

IF
    0 =
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(*)
    FROM HourIntervals
    WHERE (startHour <= @startHour AND @startHour < endHour) OR (startHour <= @endHour AND @endHour < endHour))
BEGIN
    -- Interval ok, insert your record here
    select 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Interval overlaps, don't insert
    select 0
END
```